# Multi framework Entity library missing entries

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Standard 1.6 class library for my entity structure. I'm looking to build against both .NET Standard & .NET 4.6 frameworks. I have specified both frameworks in the xproj, and excluded some files using "buildoptions" -> "compile" -> "exclude"

MyContext.cs

```
#if NETSTANDARD1_6
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyEntity
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<LogItem> Logs { get; set; }

        public static string ConnectionString =
            @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Logs;integrated security=true";

        #region Constructors

        public MyContext() { }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }

        #endregion

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
#endif

#if NET46
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace MyEntity
{
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<LogItem> Logs { get; set; }

        public static string ConnectionString =
            @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Logs;integrated security=true";

        #region Constructors

        public MyContext() : base(ConnectionString) { }
    }
}
#endif
```

This compiles but only produces the NETSTANDARD1.6 code. I look inside the .NET 4.6 library and MyContext is not included.

project.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
    "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.3.0",
    "System.Data.Common": "4.3.0",
    "System.Diagnostics.StackTrace": "4.3.0",
    "System.Linq": "4.3.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "System.Threading": "4.3.0",
    "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.3.0",
    "System.ComponentModel": "4.3.0",
    "NLog": "5.0.0-beta03",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.3.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0"
      }
    },
    "dnx46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact": "6.1.3"
      },
      "buildOptions": {
        "compile": {
          "exclude": [ "Migrations" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here you can see I've setup the two frameworks to build, and I ignore the Migrations folder with DNX46.

How do I get MyContext to be included? LogItem is included in the assembly, as this is not framework sensitive, and does not included #if statements.

I've dumped the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/wonea/EFCrossFrameworkClassLibrary), to allow for experimentation. I analyse the EFCrossFrameworkClassLibrary.dll (.NET 4.6 & .NET Standard) using [JetBrains DotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Comment: Tweak to bounty, both DLLs should contain MyContext not MyContext class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fork, please have a look at https://github.com/wonea/EFCrossFrameworkClassLibrary/pull/1

The project.json looks much clearer now!

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
      }
    },
    "net46": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "compile": {
          "exclude": [ "Migrations" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I removed most of the unused data in your project.json and added net46 as a framework. The nice thing is that EF.Core supports 'downgrading' so you don't need to do anything else (at least for your simple scenario ;-)).

This also means you don't need compile flags in the context file, so I removed them as well.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MyEntity
{
    public class LogContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<LogItem> Logs { get; set; }

        public static string ConnectionString =
            @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyLog;integrated security=true";

        #region Constructors

        public LogContext() { }

        public LogContext(DbContextOptions<LogContext> options) : base(options) { }

        #endregion

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile it and 2 folders appear in your bin: one for asp.net 4.6 and one for .net Core.

Answer (score 1):

Took the project you placed on GitHub, changed the `project.json` file a little bit and it seems to generate the `MyContext` for .Net 4.6 (you might need to update the EF dependencies for `net46`).

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Moq": "4.6.38-alpha",
    "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.3.0",
    "System.Data.Common": "4.3.0",
    "System.Diagnostics.StackTrace": "4.3.0",
    "System.Linq": "4.3.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "System.Threading": "4.3.0",
    "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.3.0",
    "System.ComponentModel": "4.3.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.3.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
        "EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact": "6.1.3"
      },
      "buildOptions": {
        "compile": {
          "exclude": [ "Migrations" ]
        }
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Core": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.1.0",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also, Inside `LogContext.cs` change:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
```

to

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the changes I had to make to get your code to compile and generate the class:

1. Change the conditional compilation to **`#if DNX46`**.
   The way you have now (**`NET46`**) is hiding another problem as the class is not actually being compiled.
2. Change namespace to `System.Data.Entity`
3. Removed the constructor `DbContextOptions` as this class does not exists on EF 6.
4. Remove the override that takes a `DbContextOptionsBuilder` because this class does not exists on EF 6.

I understand that the final class in DNX46 might not be exactly what you want as the class ends up being different than on the other framework.

Comment: You really don't need the compilation flags, please have a look at my PR https://github.com/wonea/EFCrossFrameworkClassLibrary/pull/1

Answer (score 0):

Try a framework of `net46`? In your build, make sure to target it too. On the command line that would be something like `dotnet build -f net46`.

Comment: That's odd I thought the project.json was targetting it already. I ran the command in the project folder, and; I get the error Project project.json does not support framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.

Comment: Does `net461` work? There's an example here: https://jonhilton.net/2016/09/07/using-asp-net-core-against-net-4-6/

Comment: Neither 461 or 462 works. The .NET 46 DLL does include LogItem but not MyContext.